# Search one column for string and add values to four different cells in same row

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm having an issue coding in Excel VBA. I want to run a query on all of column f for a string of 'mug', then I want to add values to column H,I,J,K.

[image: Example]

I know it's going to require a for loop to iterate through all of column f for the query of 'mug'.  After that I'm not sure how to add values to three different columns.

Pseudocoded:

```
If column f = "mug", then write 5 to column g, 10 to column h, 15 column i
```

Comment: Why use VBA, when you can use a formula?

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(FIND or SEARCH("mug",f1),"***5/10/15****"),"")

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_wordisbarn()
Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Activate
With ActiveSheet.Range("F:F")
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:="mug", _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            'Add your value in other columns
            cF.Offset(0, 1).Value = 5
            cF.Offset(0, 2).Value = 10
            cF.Offset(0, 3).Value = 15

            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```